# Component Manager Readiness Check Errors

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, dependency, component

When trying to install any extension in component manager, I end up with a bunch of errors during the readiness check. My biggest issue is:"Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is ."

My php version is 5.6.32 on both CLI and Server. I'm running magento 2.1.10 community.

I've tried the "disable-tls":false in my composer file.

More info: I'm on a shared server, meaning I'm limited on my php config. I can change the server php.ini, but not CLI. I'm locked at 128mb on CLI. Which adds all sorts of challenges.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

**Update Edit:**

Looks like my php problem was because I didn't have the cron setup correctly. I had to add both of these cron jobs pointing to my php.ini(since I can't edit the cli php.ini being a shared server):

/usr/bin/php -c /home3/user/public_html/php.ini /home3/user/public_html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home3/user/public_html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log

/usr/bin/php -c /home3/user/public_html/php.ini /home3/user/public_html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /home3/user/public_html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log

In that php.ini I've changed the memory_limit to be 2G. And then ran the following commands
php bin/magento cron:run
php update/cron.php
php bin/magento setup:cron:run

This solved all my issues but one:

[image: Component Dependency error]

Any advise on this one?

Answer (score 0):

So after continually searching online I assume this error is due to memory limit.  Is there a way to increase the memory limit for this without having access to the cli memory config?

Edit: This pretty much confirms it. var/error_log results:
[14-Mar-2018 13:49:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 655884288) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home3/nmodcom1/public_html/n-mod/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule.php on line 50

Any way to increase the memory for this command to run?